# Trigger con update, no hay manera

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

tengo estas dos tablas:

Tabla departamentos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y basicamente quiero hacer un trigger que cuando inserte o actualice algo en la tabla datos, principalmente el dinero, también lo haga en la tabla departamentos, he estado mirando por aqui y no me ha servido de mucho.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
delimiter
create trigger t1 after insert on datos
for each row
begin
  declare z int;
  select sum(dinero) into z from departamentos
  update departamentos set salario_total=z where departamentos=new.dep;
end //
```

A la hora de hacer el trigger no me da problema, es a la hora de hacer el insert.

el error que me sale es el siguiente:

> "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dinero' in field list"

Gracias de antemano :) un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué tabla es cual en las imágenes?  Tienes un error de sintaxis aquí: `selec`

Comment: Perdón, fue un error al copiar, el trigger si que me lo crea es a la hora de hacer el insert cuando me sale el error.

Comment: ¿Y qué me dices de las imágenes? No se sabe a qué tabla corresponde cada una ¿?

Comment: Joder perdon estoy tonto jeje ya lo puse bien :)

Comment: Me parece que es justo lo que te dice @OscarGarcia en su respuesta.

Comment: Siii era eso, muchas gracias por la ayuda :))

Comment: Me alegro. Marca la respuesta como solucionada y vota a favor si lo consideras oportuno. Saludos.

Comment: No sale publico porque soy nuevo pero creo que ya lo hice jeje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que las tablas de las imagenes son (Si no es asi corrigeme):
**Imagen 1:** departamentos
**Imagen 2:** datos

La tabla dinero no existe en departamentos por lo que la consulta deberia ser:

```
select sum(dinero) into z from datos
```

Pero me temo que eso no es lo que quieres hacer realmente porque lo que hace el select es sumar el total de la columna dinero de la tabla datos.
Lo que creo que quieres hacer es esto:

```
select sum(dinero) into z from datos WHERE datos.dep = new.dep
```

Por lo que el trigger quedaria algo asi(corrigiendo nombre de tablas y columnas si fuera necesario, evidentemente):

```
delimiter
create trigger t1 after insert on datos
for each row
begin
  declare z int;
  select sum(dinero) into z from datos WHERE datos.dep = new.dep
  update departamentos set salario_total=z where departamentos=new.dep;
end //
```

Espero que te funcione

Comment: SIIIIIII, muchisimas gracias :))))